# request for user out of office settings from exchange

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, soap, exchangewebservices

I'm writing rails app with MS Exchange integration,

I use gem 'exchanger' in my application.

As I see - it's easy to get information about [user availability](https://github.com/ebeigarts/exchanger/blob/master/spec/exchanger/get_user_availability_spec.rb)

But how can I get information about is user available or not at current time?
(something like Out of office badge).

Is a some way make a request to exchange for user [OutOfOffice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa493825(v=exchg.150).aspx) status and how can I do it using [exchanger gem](https://github.com/ebeigarts/exchanger)?

Please, help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your exchange user need to have a permissions to use this API.

I add new class to operations in `exchanger` gem to processing GetUserOofRequest:

```
    class Request < Operation::Request
      attr_accessor :email_address

      # Reset request options to defaults.
      def reset
        @email_address = 'test.test@test.com'
      end

      def to_xml
        Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
          xml.send("soap:Envelope", "xmlns:xsi" => NS["xsi"], "xmlns:xsd" => NS["xsd"], "xmlns:soap" => NS["soap"]) do
            xml.send("soap:Body") do
              xml.send("GetUserOofSettingsRequest", "xmlns" => NS["m"]) do
                xml.send("Mailbox", "xmlns" => NS["t"]) do
                  xml.send("Address", @email_address)
                end
              end
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
   end
```

Also you can get OOO user's status from GetUserAvailability API too 
(just set range between start_time and end time to 1 hour).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the 'exchanger' specifics, but the operation you want is [GetUserOofSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa563465(v=exchg.150).aspx).

Comment: I know about this API method, but it's to difficult for me to generate SOAP GetUserOofSettings request... Kindly ask you for help, if you can provide me some ruby example